# Textmate question: how to have a drawer when editing files online?

Tags: textmate

is it possible with Textmate to work remotely and using the sidebar drawer?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself:

- Use Transmit 4+
- Mount the server as image
- drag the entire mount icon in textmate

done.

Answer (score 1):

How do you do the "remote" part of your question? SSHFS? FTP?

If you use FTP (Transmit or Cyberduck) there is at least [one way](http://muffinresearch.co.uk/archives/2006/06/13/use-tabs-in-textmate-for-remote-files-opened-by-transmit/) but I think it's extremelly convoluted. I used to want it badly when I started to use TextMate but I soon learned about Subversion and then Git and now, I almost never use an FTP client for development work at all.

Both versioning systems are extremelly well integrated with TextMate and the whole concept of working on a local copy and pushing only valid changes is vastly superior to using an FTP client to download a whole file in a temp folder, opening it with a local editor, saving the temp file, uploading it to the server.

If you use SSHFS or some other ways to mount the remote server you can use it as you were working with local file with the caveat that the whole thing can be maddening slow.

Did you try to edit the files within an SSH session in the terminal? Using Vim like that is actually very fast but it can lead to [somewhat unpleasing situations](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2343330) when not done correctly.

Comment: for seme reason i got this maybe bad attitude to make changes directly online... i know is very bad,i use this method only for online prototype in restricted areas... i ver used git because i thought it was a pain using svn or stuff like that... but i will in future... thanks for the tip, i use transmit...so it maybe interesting to check that link out